# Is there a *Nix tool that can be used to format command output that is too wide for the screen?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, pipe

I'm running

> psql -U postgres template1 -c "select * from pg_stat_activity"

and the output is too wide for my terminal.  Is there a *nix command I can use to prevent the output from wrapping?  Maybe a setting in screen that enables virtual horizontal scrolling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
psql ... | less -S
```

The `-S` option to `less` enables horizontal scrolling instead of line wrapping.

Comment: Note that you can still scroll horizontally without `-S`. When scrolled to the first column it will wrap, but once you scroll right the text will be "unwrapped".

Comment: Interesting, I never noticed that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to (or can't) use a pager for some reason, you can also use `cut`:

```
psql ... | cut -c1-60
```

This takes only the first 60 characters of each line. No scrolling however.

Answer (score 1):

`fmt` is probably what you want; it will wrap lines at a given column.  `pr` has more options and is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding `-P format=wrapped` to your psql invocation, if you're using pg 8.4 or newer.